# Issue with OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

_

Hello guys,

I created a simple app which consists of 1 activity and 2 fragments (`ViewPager`).
Fragment 1 contains 9 buttons.

- 3 buttons for changing background color (red, blue, green)
- 3 buttons for setting a text string nr. (1, 2 3)
- 3 buttons for 3 modes (A, B, C)

Fragment 2 contains 1 `TextView` only which gets modified by the buttons of fragment 1.

As soon as a button of Fragment 1 gets pressed, the `TextView` of Fragment 2 gets refreshed.

Example:
I am in Mode A and press color red and String 1
Then I switch to Mode B and choose blue and String 2.
In Mode C I choose green and string 3.
Now when switching back to Mode A, the TextView of Fragment 2 is red and 1.

Everything works perfectly, but when pressing on a mode button, the textview does not get refreshed.
I always have to change the view from protrait to landscape or vice versa.

When I just click on Nr. or color, I see the change immediatelly.
It seems the `OnPreferenceChangeListener` doesn't recognize the mode button click but the other button clicks.

What to do?

Fragment 1:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{
    Button buttonModeA, buttonModeB, buttonModeC, buttonRed, buttonBlue, buttonGreen, buttonNr1, buttonNr2, buttonNr3;
    TextView textViewNr;
    String mode, text;
    int bColor; // Background color for textview
    SharedPreferences prefsMode; // Specific SharedPreferences (modes)

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View fragmentOne = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false); // Link view and layout
        buttonModeA = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_load_a);
        buttonModeB = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_load_b);
        buttonModeC = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_load_c);
        buttonRed = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_red);
        buttonBlue = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_blue);
        buttonGreen = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_green);
        buttonNr1 = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_nr_1);
        buttonNr2 = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_nr_2);
        buttonNr3 = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_nr_3);

        loadModeAndSettings(); // Load SharedPreferences
        buttonModeA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mode = "A"; // Set mode to A
                saveMode(); // Save selected mode
                loadModeAndSettings();
            }
        });
        buttonModeB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mode = "B"; // Set mode to B
                saveMode(); // Save selected mode
                loadModeAndSettings();
            }
        });
        buttonModeC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mode = "C"; // Set mode to C
                saveMode(); // Save selected mode
                loadModeAndSettings();
            }
        });
        buttonRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {
                bColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red); // Set background color to red
                saveSettings(); // Save settings
            }
        });
        buttonBlue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {
                bColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue); // Set background color to blue
                saveSettings(); // Save settings
            }
        });
        buttonGreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {
                bColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.green); // Set background color to green
                saveSettings(); // Save settings
            }
        });
        buttonNr1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {
                animationEffect(buttonNr1); // Start animation for this button
                text = "1"; // Set text to 1
                saveSettings(); // Save settings
            }
        });
        buttonNr2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {
                text = "2"; // Set text to 2
                saveSettings(); // Save settings
            }
        });
        buttonNr3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {
                text = "3"; // Set text to 3
                saveSettings(); // Save settings
            }
        });
        return fragmentOne;
    }
    public void saveMode()
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE); // Create new SharedPreferences instance
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); // Create access variable for editor
        editor.putString("mode", mode); // Put received value for mode into editor
        editor.apply(); // Save + close instance
    }
    public void saveSettings()
    {
        SharedPreferences prefsMode = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF_"+mode, MODE_PRIVATE); // Create new SharedPreferences instance for selected mode
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorMode = prefsMode.edit(); // Create access variable for editor
        editorMode.putInt("bColor", bColor); // Put received value into editor
        editorMode.putString("text", text); // Put received value into editor
        editorMode.apply(); // Save + close instance
    }
    public void loadModeAndSettings()
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE); // Load saved shared file
        mode = prefs.getString("mode", "A"); // mode or default value: A
        prefsMode = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF_"+mode, MODE_PRIVATE); // Retrieve current prefsMode
        bColor = prefsMode.getInt("bColor", 0); // Load value of background color or default value
        text = prefsMode.getString("text", "default"); // Load value of text string or default value
    }
}
```

Fragment 2:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment
{
    TextView textViewNr; // Visual feedback for color and nr.
    String mode, text; // Mode for SharedPreferences and text nr. for textViewNr
    int bColor; // Background color for textView
    SharedPreferences prefsMode; // Specific SharedPreferences (modes)
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener; // Access variable for SharedPreferencesChangeListener

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View fragmentTwo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false); // Link view and layout
        textViewNr = fragmentTwo.findViewById(R.id.text_view_nr); // Link variable to ID
        loadModeAndSettings(); // Load SharedPreferences
        preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() // Check if SharedPreferences have been changed
        {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
            {
                loadModeAndSettings(); // Load settings and refresh views if anything has been changed
            }
        };
        prefsMode.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener); // Apply changes
        return fragmentTwo;
    };
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (preferenceChangeListener != null)
        {
            prefsMode.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
        }
    }
    public void loadModeAndSettings() // Load mode and its settings
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE); // Load saved shared file
        mode = prefs.getString("mode", "A"); // mode or default value: A
        prefsMode = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF_"+mode, MODE_PRIVATE); // Retrieve current prefsMode
        bColor = prefsMode.getInt("bColor", 0); // Load value of background color or default value
        text = prefsMode.getString("text", "default"); // Load value of text string or default value
        updateGui(); // Update all views
    }
    public void updateGui() // Refresh views
    {
        textViewNr.setBackgroundColor(bColor); // Update background color of textViewMode
        textViewNr.setText(text); // Update text of textViewMode
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Best regards

Comment: Hello again. Do you think it's more meaningful not to work with the OnSharedPreferencesListener when switching a mode? For the text or nr. button presses it works flawlessly, and I might continue using it for that. But for switching modes the better way might be a real refresh of the fragment which gets changed. In fragment2 I added the tag: private static final String TAG = "fragment2". In fragment1 I tried adding several code blocks inside of the onClickMethod of Mode A - nothing worked, though (Crash: Null Pointer Exception.) Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_
Hello experts,

I solved the problem by using an exploit.

I simply added a DummyActivity which closes itself as soon as it gets called.

After clicking on a mode button in fragment1, I create an intent to start this DummyActivity - by updating my existing saveMode method.

(I do not feel or see anything of this RunActivity/Close Activity process - at least on the Emulator).

In Fragment2 I moved 95% of the code, which was in onCreateView, in the onResume.

Well, it works perfectly!

P.S. Maybe there's a cleaner solution, though.

Best regards